# Reduce a Map where the keys are values in some entries

Tags: java, dictionary, hashmap

I am trying to make a new Map from a another Map where some of the values are keys in other entries.

Example:

```
HashMap<String,String> testMap = new HashMap<>();
testMap.put("a","b");
testMap.put("b","d");
testMap.put("d","e");
testMap.put("e","f");
testMap.put("k","r");
```

I need as result a new Map with this format:

`a->f`
`b->f`
`d->f`
`e->f`
`k->r`

```
producedMap.put("a","f");
producedMap.put("b","f");
producedMap.put("d","f");
producedMap.put("e","f");
producedMap.put("k","r");
```

My code is that, but seems not give the true result.

```
    public HashMap<String,String> getMatched(HashMap<String,String> correpondanceMap){

    Collection<String> correpondanceKeys = correpondanceMap.keySet();
    HashMap<String,String> newCorrepondanceMap= new HashMap<>();
    correpondanceMap.entrySet().forEach(entry->{
        if (correpondanceKeys.contains(entry.getValue())){
            String newValue = entry.getValue();
            String keyOfnewValue = correpondanceMap
                    .entrySet()
                    .stream()
                    .filter(entriii -> newValue.equals(entry.getValue()))
                    .map(Map.Entry::getKey).limit(1).collect(Collectors.joining());


            newCorrepondanceMap.put(keyOfnewValue,correpondanceMap.get(newValue));
        }
        else
        {
            newCorrepondanceMap.put(entry.getKey(),entry.getValue());
        }
    });

    newCorrepondanceMap.entrySet().forEach(entry-> System.out.println(entry.getKey() +"  -- > " +entry.getValue()));

    return newCorrepondanceMap;
}
```

Comment: could you please post the currently produced map, so it is easier to find out your problem

Comment: @Lino if we have ("a","b") and somewhere ("b","d"), we redirect simply the key "a" to the value "d"

Comment: Your question and code is unclear. What is the actual rule for re-mapping keys and values other than `a->f`, `b->f`, etc?

Comment: No I mean the output you have with your current code. E.g. what you have printed when you run your code

Comment: @Karol Dowbecki a->f because we have a->b and b->d and d->e and e->f it's like we have multipe redirections so we redirect a to f

Comment: @Dr.Mza Will the keys always be alphabetized? I.e. `a -> b` will always be before `b -> d`?

Comment: @JustinAlbano it's a HashMap; therefore the order of the keys is unpredictable.

Comment: @Justin We don't care about the order a and b can be like any string

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can achieve that by some simple recursion logic in a helper function:

```
public static String findCorrespondingValue(Map<String, String> map, String key){
    if(map.containsKey(key)){
        return findCorrespondingValue(map, map.get(key));
    }
    return key;
}
```

As said the logic is very simple, we just check if for a given `key` a value exists in the given `map`

- if yes we then execute the function again, but this time with the `value` as the 
  new `key`.
- if no mapping exists we can safely say that the `key` given is the last 
  value in the chain

You can call the method like this:

```
Map<String, String> testMap = ... // setup testMap

Map<String, String> result = new HashMap<>();
for (final Entry<String, String> entry : testMap.entrySet()) {
    result.put(
        entry.getKey(), 
        findCorrespondingValue(testMap, entry.getValue())
    );
}
```

or if you happend to use java 8:

```
Map<String, String> result = testMap.entrySet().stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
        e -> e.getKey(),  // or just Map.Entry::getKey
        e -> findCorrespondingValue(e.getValue())
     ));
```

---

You of course would have to implement some kind of logic to find out if you have cyclic references. E.g:

```
a -> b
b -> f
f -> a
```

Which would currently just fail with a `StackOverflowError`.

---

You can make this also generic if you want to support multiple different types, not just `String`:

```
public static <T> T findCorrespondingValue(Map<? extends T, ? extends T> map, T key){
    if(map.containsKey(key)){
        return findCorrespondingValue(map, map.get(key));
    }
    return key;
}
```